# Difference between Past simple & perfect

Tags: present-perfect

Could somebody tell me if I'm right with my explanation below:

1. I loved her as soon as we met : (I don't love her anymore right now)
2. I've loved her as soon as we met : (I'm still in love with her right now)

Thanks

Comment: (1) is ungrammatical (and it wouldn't mean that if it were grammatical). The [perfect construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299) is much more complex than the past tense. And did you really mean to say "Present simple" in the title?

Comment: "I loved her from our first meeting until... [whatever made their feelings change]". _Since_ always implies _until now_.

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks I update my question

Comment: Since you edited your question neither sentence is idiomatic. My previous comment applied to (1). (2) could be expressed as "I've loved her since _we first met/the first time we met/the moment we met_".

Comment: @KateBunting So How to express : I've loved her as soon as I met her (I am still in love with her) ?

Comment: The three options I gave you _do_ express exactly that. _I loved her as soon as I met her_ would be idiomatic, but doesn't necessarily express the idea that I still do.

Comment: Thanks a lot....      :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I loved her since as soon as we met : (I don't love her anymore right now)

"Since as soon as we met" doesn't sound good; "since the moment we met" sounds much better. But the word "since" implies that the condition is still ongoing; to talk about a condition that has stopped, use "from" instead of "since".

So the way I would say this is: **I loved her from the moment we met.**

This sentence implies that either I stopped loving her at some point, or she's gone now (because she died, left, or went missing).

> I've loved her as soon as we met : (I'm still in love with her right now)

This sentence, unlike the first sentence, *does* need the word "since". Like the first sentence, it sounds best if we say "the moment" instead of "as soon as".

So I'd write this sentence as: **I've loved her since the moment we met.** This means that I loved her then, and I love her now, and I've never stopped loving her.